# Raise a decimal to a decimal power in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, exponentiation

I'm writing a SQLServer query on Microsoft Azure where I need to raise the power of a small decimal (0 < x < 10) to 4.5.  e.g. 3.1^4.5

I've written the query like this:

```
case when a.avgRating = null then (6-r.WebRating)^4.5 else a.avgRating end AS avgRating
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Operand data type decimal is invalid for '^' operator.
```

I'm not sure if it's referring to the base (6-WebRating) or the exponent (4.5), but either way, I'm not sure how to get this done in SQLServer.  Works in Excel, fwiw :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `POWER` instead. And also, you shouldn't use `somecolumn = NULL` but `somecolumn IS NULL`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.avgRating IS NULL THEN POWER(6-r.WebRating,4.5) 
    ELSE a.avgRating 
END AS avgRating
```

Comment: For good measure, it is worth mentioning that `^` is the bitwise exclusive or operator, not exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you ever have the functions `exp` and `log` you have `a^b`:

```
a^b = exp(b * log(a))
```